# Should I use "toil" or "toils" when I refer to hardwork?

Tags: grammatical-number

I know toil means hardwork, even physical labor.

For example, I want to say:

I'm prepared for the toil as a oilfield worker in Siberia.

My question is: should this "toil" be "toil" (singular) or "toils" (plural)?

Thank you.

Comment: Since there are *toils* associated with being an oil farmer, I would use the plural form in your example, but I'm not sure if that's a definite rule of not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a non-accountable noun, toil as singular is to be used with the meaning of hard labour. 
Toils in the plural form means something that hinders or traps.

Comment: I think you're right.  Think of other similar nouns, like labor, torment.  Singular form would be used.

Answer (score 1):

'Toils' has a slightly different meaning to 'toil'. Whilst physical work is 'toil', 'toils' is used in reference to a situation regarded as a trap:

*Henry had become caught in the toils of his own deviousness*

Oxford Dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Your example uses toil as a non-count noun, similar to "work", but meaning very difficult work, especially physically exhausting labor.
In looking for usage examples on http://wordnik.com, I found more ancient usage of it used as a count noun in plural:
The Atlantic Monthly, Volume 17, No. 102, April, 1866
-- Ask her what Heracles would have been, what your own Theseus would have been, if they had listened to the voice of pleasure, and shrunk back from toil: their toils were the only check upon wickedness, which else must have overrun the whole.

Of course when "toil" is used as a verb, the "s" is added following the rules of subject-verb agreement.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard toils to be used in singular. Toils are like challenges. There is never only one.

Similar saying is trials and tribulations. There never is just one, unless the first one kills you and you are dead. Then no further toils will happen. But also then you won't live to tell the tale either.

After looking @
http://thesaurus.com/browse/toil
and
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/toil

You can say I'm prepared for the toil.

Examples from thesaurus.com

It was late because that's when many of the guests, who **toil** in restaurant kitchens, got off work.

Their **toil** feeds the world's hunger for gold, and leaves a ruined landscape in its wake.

The bridge project took four years of **toil** under brutal conditions.

Artists struggling to make ends meet **toil** for days for a pittance.